# import matplotlib.animation fails due to `convert`

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, matplotlib

I'm trying to run the example live chart from https://pythonprogramming.net/live-graphs-matplotlib-tutorial/, which begins with (and this is the full text of the source that fails):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

The second import fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.animation as animation
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 737, in <module>
    class ImageMagickWriter(ImageMagickBase, MovieWriter):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 120, in wrapper
    if writerClass.isAvailable():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 730, in isAvailable
    return super().isAvailable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 427, in isAvailable
    return shutil.which(cls.bin_path()) is not None
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 724, in bin_path
    binpath = mpl._get_executable_info('magick').executable
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 384, in _get_executable_info
    return impl([path, "--version"], r"^Version: ImageMagick (\S*)")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 329, in impl
    raise _cpe
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 324, in impl
    args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['convert', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 4.
```

I'm running python 3.6 under Cygwin on Win10.  All Cygwin packages were updated or installed yesterday.

`convert` is a Windows program to convert filesystems and doesn't have a `--version` option (or any options beginning with `--`.)  Any idea what convert command is intended here?

Comment: convert is meant to be the `convert` executable of `imagemagick`. This means the imagemagick bin folder needs to be part of the system PATH, or better, the respective matplotlib rcParam needs to point to the imagemagick convert tool.

Comment: There is a Windows convert and an Imagemagick convert. Perhaps you are calling the Windows convert when you want the Imagemagick convert. Try renaming the Imagemagick convert and use that in your subprocess call

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - Thanks!  I just had to install imagemagik.  There must be a missing dependency between matplotlab and imagemagik.  Add it as an answer and you'll get the points.

Comment: But sadly, the example fails ... the graph is hidden until all the data has been consumed.  Probably just doesn't work under Cygwin.  But that's another issue.

Comment: Yes, actually, just importing `matplotlib.animation` shouldn't need imagemagick installed; one would expect it to only be needed in case an animation is saved via `ani.save(..., writer="imagemagick")`. So it might be a bug in the sense that the exception should be caught instead of raised on the user level.

Comment: A similar issue (yet with a slightly different error) just came in [#14902](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14902), looks like a real bug.